# Python zmq connections

Tags: python, zeromq

I tried to use python's zmq lib. And now I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to check socket connection state?
   I'd like to know if connection is established after call `connect`
2. I want to one-to-one communication model.
   I tried to use `PAIR` zmq socket type.
   In that case if one client is already connected, server will not receive any messages from secondary connected client.
   But I'd like to get info in the second client that there is another client and server is busy.

Answer (score -1):

1. You'd get an error if `connect` fails.
   But I guess the real question is how often do you want to check this? once at startup, before each message, or periodically, using some `heartbeat`?
2. That does not make sense, as you can not send info without connecting first.
   However, some socket types might give some more info.

But the best way would be to use multiple sockets: one for such status information, and another one for sending data.
ZMQ is made to use multiple sockets.

Comment: hm...```connect``` will not raise some error. It'll try to connect.

Comment: inn other words. I'd like to in runtime is connection established.

Comment: switch the `bind` and `connect`.  it will show `zmq.error.ZMQError: Address already in use` when starting the 'bind side'  two times.

Comment: and use ```bind``` for client part?